# How can we get messages from an MQTT broker and put them into the ZeroMQ queue?

Tags: mqtt, zeromq

I am trying to get messages from an MQTT broker and insert that messages into ZeroMQ. What do I need to do to connect an MQTT broker to [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) in java?

Comment: This question seems (to a non-expert) quite broad. What have you done so far, and what part of this are you struggling with. Where are your references?

Comment: [Learn the Basics](http://zeromq.org/intro:read-the-manual) can help you getting started. Try it and ask about a more specific problem.

Comment: I was just wondering, were you able to do that ?. I have created a proxy between MQTT broker publisher and ZeroMQ as a subscriber using XPUB and ZSUB, however, it seems that the ZeroMQ doesn't receive any message from MQTT broker, any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is merge together the MQTT subscriber code with a ZeroMQ sender in Java, such that when you receive a message from the MQTT queue, it gets transferred to the 0MQ for 0MQ listeners to receive.

I haven't used MQTT from Java, but a popular library seems to be [Paho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715682/subscribe-and-read-mqtt-message-using-paho).

The 0MQ documentation and example code is excellent, and a Java example can be found [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:hwclient).